# Spark connectivity issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming program that connects to a DatahighWay and it works fine if i run the program via Run. But if I create a jar and run the jar via spark-submit I get the following error. Does this mean there are some issues in spark connecting to one of it's executor nodes? It is run in local machine.

```
18/05/02 22:52:20 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/05/02 22:52:20 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Receiver has been stopped. Try to restart it.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.184.199.182:62431
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:480)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:696)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:688)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation timed out: /10.184.199.182:62431
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.184.199.182:62431
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:480)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:696)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:688)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation timed out: /10.184.199.182:62431
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
```

It seems like a connection issue, not sure how it is happening.

Comment: where your data is stored? is HDFS or S3? make sure your spark nodes could access your storage.

Comment: @SharpLu - It is getting it via kafka broker. Also I am working in vpn, if that could be an issue